# How to get URL ID into MySQL query for CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Basically, this is what I wanted to do, how does it work?

```
public function get_product_category(){


        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);


        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM products where category_id = $id  ');


        return $query->row();           
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Query Builder Class](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html)

```
public function get_product_category(){

  $this->db->where('category_id', $this->uri->segment(3));
  $query = $this->db->get('products');

  return $query->row();
  // return $query->row_array();

}
```

Or

```
public function get_product_category(){

  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('products');
  $this->db->where('category_id', $this->uri->segment(3));
  $query = $this->db->get();

  return $query->row();
  // return $query->row_array();

}
```

I would autoload the database library.